Apply labels in bulk from a dataset
I have a dataset labels that has two columns: variable and label, and a second dataset data that is my actual dataset, with columns corresponding to variables in labels (nrow in labels = ncol in data). I would like to apply each label using some sort of macro, instead of typing each individually.
In a small dataset, it can be achieved with:
proc sql;
    select "label " || variable|| " = '" || label || "';"
    into :labels separated by " "
    from labels;
quit;

data data;
    set data;

    &labels.;
run;

However, in this case, due to the size of the dataset I end up with a huge macro variable &labels. that gets truncated. Is there another way of doing this?

Use a data step and write the code to a file.  Then use %INC  to run the code.  Use PROC DATATSETS lib=work;  MODIFY data; %inc your-file; run; quit;  No need to create a new data set just to modify labels.

Use PROC DATASETS and CALL EXECUTE.
*Create label data set;
data label_data_set;
length name label $25.;
name="Sex"; label="Gender"; output;
name="height"; label="Height (in)"; output;
name="weight"; label="Weight (lbs)"; output;
run;
 
 
*Create sample dataset to apply label;
data class;
set sashelp.class;
run;



*change to reflect your data set;
%let lib2update = work; /*library where data set to be changed is stored*/
%let data2update = class; /*dataset to be modified*/
%let label_data = label_data_set; /*dataset with the labels*/


*********************************************************;
*DO NOT CHANGE AFTER THIS LINE;
**********************************************************;
title 'Data set before updates';
ods select variables;
proc contents data=&data2update;
run;


*proc datasets implementation of changes;
data _null_;
set &label_data. end=eof;

if _n_ = 1 then call execute(catt("proc datasets lib= &lib2update nolist nodetails; modify &data2update; label "));

str = catx("=", name, quote(label));
call execute (str);
call execute(" ");

if eof then call execute('; run;quit;');
run;

*check results;
title 'Data set after updates';
ods select variables;
proc contents data=&data2update;
run;

Link to methods: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/f18931085f6a0009185c

Per @"data _null_", write label statement snippets to a codegen file and then include that file as part of a Proc DATASETS step.
Example:
data labels ;
  length variable $32 label $200 ;
  do i = 1 to 100 ;
    variable = cats('x',i) ;
    label = cats('Measurement X[',i,']') ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;

data have ;
  array x x1-x5 ;
run ;

proc contents noprint data=have out=contents(keep=name) ;
proc sort data=contents ; by name ;
proc sort data=labels; by variable ;

filename codegen temp ;
data _null_;
  merge contents (in=var_in_have rename=name=variable) labels (in=var_in_labels) ;
  by variable ;
  file codegen ;
  if var_in_have and var_in_labels then put variable '=' label: $quote200. ;
run ;

proc datasets noprint lib=work ;
  modify have ;
  label 
  %include codegen /source2 ;
  ;
run ;

filename codegen ;

Will Log
311  proc datasets noprint lib=work ;
312    modify have ;
313    label
314    %include codegen /source2 ;
NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) file CODEGEN is file C:\Users\radev\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary
      Files\_TD9700_GOLDY_\#LN00089.
315 +x1 ="Measurement X[1]"
316 +x2 ="Measurement X[2]"
317 +x3 ="Measurement X[3]"
318 +x4 ="Measurement X[4]"
319 +x5 ="Measurement X[5]"
NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) ending.
320    ;
321  run ;

NOTE: MODIFY was successful for WORK.HAVE.DATA.


Truncation of a >64K long source code snippet created by INTO :<macrovar> can be avoided by trimming the fat.

Use TRIM(VARIABLE) and TRIM(label), or use CATS or CATX
Don't create multiple label statements, instead create the snippet for a single label statement.
Use DICTIONARY.COLUMNS or SASHELP.VCOLUMN to ensure labels are being applied to only variables that are present in the data set
Use Proc DATASETS to alter the metadata of a data set

%let labels = ;
proc sql;
    select CATX('=', variable, quote(label))
    into :labels separated by " "
    from labels 
    where upcase(variable) 
       in ( select upcase(name) from DICTIONARY.COLUMNS
            where libname = 'WORK' and memname = 'MYDATA'
          )
    ;
quit ;

proc datasets lib=work ;
  modify mydata ;
  label &labels ;
quit ;

A worst case of all variable names being 32 characters long and all labels being 200 characters long will allow ~275 variables to be labelled via a single macro variable.  If you suppose names ~15 and labels ~50 a macro variable can handle labelling ~950 variables.
